# how to set selected default font size on font size drop down in tinymce 3.5.8

Tags: tinymce

I am using tiny mce 3.5.8 .i already set default font size is 14px in the tiny mce editor using ed.execCommand("fontSize", true,"14px");.But on the time of rendering font size 12px text shows.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is telling the Font Size select list to set itself to the 14px selection but that won't impact the HTML that is already loaded into the editor.

If you want the content in the editor to default to using 14px you should pass a CSS file into TinyMCE (see the `content_css` init setting) and set the default font size to 14px in that CSS file.

If you load content and then manually use the font size select to set the size you will see that TinyMCE wraps the selection in a span and applies an inline style.  You could certainly also do that as you load the content into TinyMCE but then you have a hard-coded font size.

I would think the CSS approach will do what you want while making it easier to change your default font size later if you need to do so.